# Windows XP SP3 - Cannot initialize DVDs

Tags: windows-xp

I upgraded from Windows XP SP2 to SP3.  Now, I cannot create DVD disks.  The option to initialize a blank disk disappeared (no longer there when I right-click on the drive in My Computer).  Any suggestions how to get that ability back?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the software that came with your dvd burner to burn dvd's. Or better, use other free software such as Imgburn or CDBurnerxp. Many more listed here: http://www.filehippo.com/software/dvd/

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry that I can not help you as I can not test this easily. If you want to go down this route, I hope someone else will come along with a good answer. However:

For burning disks, I would highly recommend [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) (Available on [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) for quick installation).

It works very well and allows you to perform many disk operations.

Alternatively, if you just want a very light weight solution that can look like it is part of Windows / a standard file operation, take a look at [ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/)